# What is Buddhism and who is Buddhist?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, traditions

There was recently a question about chakras -- [What are the original colors of the 7 main chakras?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/46455/254) -- which, while not being particularly well asked, was closed with a raft of negative comments saying things like “chakras are Hindu not Buddhist” and “Buddhism doesn’t accept chakras”.

It is not hard to find chakras in Buddhism. Ancient Buddhism no less. There are long-standing systems and Buddhist traditions that have been practicing with and teaching chakras, going back as far as the 6thC or before.  Sure, they aren’t found in the Pali canon - but “Buddhism” as a topic does not stop at the Pali canon.

It would be far more honourable and noble for editors and answerers to stick to the areas of Buddhism that they know something about, rather than to make spurious claims and pronouncements about what they know nothing of.

As I commented in the said question, to claim that chakras are not found in Buddhism is tantamount to saying that the Dalai Lama is not Buddhist. Not only him, but all four schools of traditional Tibet, as well as numerous other traditions of Vietnam, Nepal, China, Korea, Japan, and elsewhere.

You may not like it, but these traditions are long-standing Buddhist, traditions and are recognised as such globally. From the ‘50s (and earlier) vast amounts of work was invested into recognising the importance of working together as Buddhist traditions - not some weird unified catholic sangha but a mutual recognition of diversity and practice within the framework of the teachings of Our Lord Buddha.

Can we please get this sorted out once and for all?  Those who can close - please close for good reasons, not for ignorant ones.

And commentors - really. It’s important to qualify the scope of your comments: who could dispute that ‘chakras are not found in the Pali canon’? But it is too easy to dispute ‘Buddhism’.  You only need to open any number of Buddhist texts of eg the Tibetan Kanjur (the repository of Sanskrit source texts translated into Tibetan) to find mention of chakra.

Comment: For instance, "Death Intermediate State and Rebirth in Tibetan Buddhism" / Lati Rinpoche & Jeffrey Hopkins from pages 14 ... 67 are all about chakras and how they interact with various states of consciousness at death.  There are many publications that detail chakras this way.

Answer (score 2):

Tibetan Buddhism and Vajrayana are certainly recognized as part of Buddhism on this site.

I was genuinely unaware that chakras are a part of this tradition and so was another moderator.

The question has been reopened.

Comment: I didn't know one way or the other (and so I didn't close it). An alternative to closing it (in case of doubt) might be to leave it open, or to post a comment to ask which school/tradition they're asking about.

Comment: @ChrisW Chakras are quite famous as being part of Kundalini Yoga in Hinduism, which has exactly 7 chakras, each with a visualization, color and sound, plus the two nadis and the serpent energy rising up the spine. OTOH, chakras don't seem to be very prominent in Vajrayana. I think the original questioner has no idea either.

Comment: @ruben2020, while the questioner is indeed ill-informed, the use of chakras in Vajrayana is very prominent within what is known as the 'completion stage'.  The very oldest tantras are involved with chakras via 'winds/channels/drops' language.  Cf. my comment above (Lati Rinpoche) - a non-tantric text that is informed by tantra, discussing the physical mechanism of rebirth.  The reason why you may have seen less of it is that it is a 'hidden' practice.  I would be interested to know what sources you use for Vajrayana.

Answer (score 2):

> Can we please get this sorted out once and for all?

If you do see a mistake, then thank you for commenting as you did, to help correct it.